# How use Material Style in pyside?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtquick2, pyside6

I have pyside6 application,I want to set the style of application to Material Design so I set `sys.argv += ['--style', 'material']` in below:

```
import sys,os
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal, QTimer, QUrl
import PySide6

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE'] = "material"
    #==================================================
    sys.argv += ['--style', 'material']
    #==================================================
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "qml/main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I giving the error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///D:/QtProjects/qtforpythonprojects/JooyaTrader01/qml/main.qml: module "material" is not installed
```

I recently install Qt 6 and I use pyside6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in Qt6 the names are more restrictive than Qt5 in the names so you should use "Material" instead of "material".

Comment: @mohsen mmm, explain yourself better

Comment: @It will diplay the button incorrectly,I will update question soon

Comment: I inserted that in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66529438/incorrect-display-of-material-design-in-pyside6