# How should I use Material Design in Pyside6 Application?

Tags: qt, qml, material-design, pyside, pyside6

I have below code in my pyside 6 app

```
import sys,os
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal, QTimer, QUrl
import PySide6

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #for error -> Failed to create vertex shader(It is displaying empty window)
    os.environ['QT_QUICK_BACKEND'] = "software"

    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE'] = "Material"
    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_THEME'] = "Dark"
    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_VARIANT'] = "Dense"
    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_ACCENT'] = "Teal"
    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_PRIMARY'] = "BlueGrey"
#    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_FOREGROUND'] = "Brown"
#    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_BACKGROUND'] = "Grey"
    #==================================================
    sys.argv += ['--style', 'Material']
    #==================================================
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "qml/main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id:mainWindow
    flags: Qt.Window//|Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    width: 1000
    height: 580
    visible: true
//    Material.theme:Material.Light
//    Material.primary: Material.color("#d81b60",Material.Shade600)
//    Material.accent: Material.color(Material.Pink,Material.Shade800)
    Material.elevation:2
    Button{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Material.accent: Material.Orange
        text: "Open"
        width: 150
        height: 45
        onClicked: {
             mainWindow.Material.theme===Material.Light? mainWindow.Material.theme=Material.Dark: mainWindow.Material.theme=Material.Light
        }
    }
}
```

I have a button in center of page but effects is appearing in x=0 and y=0,and it don't display color of primary and accent

[image]

**Edit**

For more infomation may be helps for understanding where is problem:

I disabled using material design in my project now after running the application When I hover on button I see below on application output:

```
file:///C:/Users/MyUserName/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python39/site-packages/PySide6/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Windows/Button.qml:77:49:
 Unable to assign [undefined] to int
```

When I click above link(in application output) It will show code of `Button.qml`

```
NativeStyle.Button {
        control: control
        x: background.x
        y: background.y
        width: background.width
        height: background.height
        useNinePatchImage: false
        overrideState: NativeStyle.StyleItem.AlwaysHovered
        opacity: control.hovered ? 1 : 0
//*********** It will jump in below by clicking on that
        Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: parent.transitionDuration } }
    }
```

When I click button application will crash.I think it is because of `stackview.Push("page.qml")` and `StackView` has animation for pushing page,I think it will crash beacuse my app has problem with animation

And another thing to say:
I installed Python 3.9.2 in `Program Files folder` but when I use `pip install pyside6 or ...` It will copy the file in `C:/Users/MyUserName/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python39/site-packages` path

Comment: try changing `os.environ['QT_QUICK_BACKEND'] = "software"` to `os.environ['QSG_RHI'] = "1"`

Comment: @eyllanesc Now It don't display the button but by clicking on that it works .But in application window I have this error: `Failed to create vertex shader: Error 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
Failed to build graphics pipeline state`

Comment: @eyllanesc By click on button `mainWindow.Material.theme===Material.Light? mainWindow.Material.theme=Material.Dark: mainWindow.Material.theme=Material.Light` Just the backgroud color is changing

Comment: I only get the error that you indicate in your post when I use the "software" option (I think there is a bug). Do you have OpenGL installed?

Comment: @eyllanesc NO I don't installed OpenGL

Comment: @eyllanesc how install it? by using? `pip install opengl` ?

Comment: @eyllanesc I installed opengle driver for my griphic card.the problem is still there

Comment: @eyllanesc Qt Creator intellisense don't display Material and many other like Qt.AlignHCenter and ... ,does it mean that somthing is incorrect.may be somthing is not installed?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have Qt 6.0.2 and Qt 5.12.2 ,Could the problem be that pyside6 was using the wrong version?

Comment: @eyllanesc I changed to pyside2,Now I have no problem,Do you know where is the problem with pyside6?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message error too when I hover on Button.

The problem here is this line:

```
Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: parent.transitionDuration } }
```

And more precisely because 'duration' property needs an integer and the value of 'parent.transitionDuration' is undefined (which means that it doesn't exist). With a little more investigation, it seems that the 'transitionDuration' is a property for NativeStyle.Button, but "parent" is a QQuickLoader.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
NativeStyle.Button {
        id: nsButton // <-------- add an id
        control: control
        x: background.x
        y: background.y
        width: background.width
        height: background.height
        useNinePatchImage: false
        overrideState: NativeStyle.StyleItem.AlwaysHovered
        opacity: control.hovered ? 1 : 0

        // by doing this you will be able to change the 'parent' for the id
        Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: nsButton.transitionDuration } }
    }
```

EDIT:
This is a partial answer, for those who have the message error.