# Can I add the Material Design style to PySide6 under Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: qt, pyqt, material-design, ubuntu-20.04, pyside6

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and want to write a Python application with a GUI so I decided to go with PySide6 and to make the application look nice I would like to use the Material Design style like in the screenshots here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html.

I found several questions like this one: [How should I use Material Design in Pyside6 Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66529438/how-should-i-use-material-design-in-pyside6-application?noredirect=1&lq=1), but after finding out that nothing is working I read somewhere that `QStyleFactory.keys()` would list the available styles that I can use. Turns out the only styles I can use are `Windows` and `Fusion`. So no wonder I can't use `Material` as style. Is there any way I can add this style? Like downloading or installing this specific style somehow?

---

Be aware that I'm new to working with Qt so if I omitted some crucial detail (because I don't know what detail may be crucial for this) just ask for it.

---

I also found https://pypi.org/project/qt-material/ but to me it looks a bit off from the "real" Material Design. I don't want to use this.

Comment: "after finding out that nothing is working" meaning that you were not able to use it? The "classical" widget side of Qt doesn't have any material style. You either use the "qt-material" you linked, or you learn how to customize it.

Comment: I am not able to use it, right. There seem to be major differences between QWidgets and QML stuff which is surprising to me as I thought each one is just another representation of the other one. Also having to customize the widgets myself is not what I am looking for.

Comment: QML was created for different purposes, it works very differently and has completely different API and interfaces. While it supports basic standard "widgets" (buttons, combo boxes, views, etc. just like any UI toolkit), they are *not* Qt widgets nor they could be. I suggest you to read more carefully the documentation, starting from here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html If you're still not able to use it, then I suggest you to create a separate question with a proper [mre].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should learn the difference between QtWidgets and QtQuick/QML. I guess you want to work with QtWidget. There is no material design solution for QtWidgets provided by Qt company because material design is not primarily targeted for desktop while QtWidgets are. But there is a custom library, very nice IMHO, https://github.com/laserpants/qt-material-widgets

Comment: Ok it surprises me to hear that there is a difference, I thought QML was just another representation of the widgets and layout. The linked custom library looks nice, but it seems I will have to take another look at QML.

Answer (score -1):

You can use QMaterialWidgets, the repo link is https://github.com/zhiyiYo/QMaterialWidgets